# Chrome: getCurrentPosition timeout after watchPosition was called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation

This issue happens on Google chrome:

If I simply use getCurrentPosition, it works just perfect.

However, if I first call watchPosition and then try to use getCurrentPosition, it times out.
Here's the jsfiddle that represents the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Js6sm/

```
function watchLocation(callback)
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(pos){
            showPosition(pos);
            callback(pos);
    }, function(err){
        alert(err.message);
    }, {
        timeout: 2000
    });
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

function getLocation(callback)
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
            showPosition(pos);
            callback(pos);
        }, function(err){
            alert(err.message);
        }, {
            timeout: 2000
        });
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

function showPosition(position)
  {
  alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "\r\n"
    +"Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude); 
  }

getLocation(function(){
    alert(0);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        watchLocation(function(){

            alert(1);
            window.setTimeout(function(){

                getLocation(function(){
                    alert(2);
                });

            }, 1000);

        });
    }, 1000);    
});
```

It seems to me that I first need to call clearWatch in order to make the position retrieval work.

Am I missing anything?